# Why is innerHTML = "" slow in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, browser

I am testing the speed of different methods to dynamically add html elements to the DOM. I've build a tester [here](http://www.nicon.nl/testhtml/elwrap_.html) (code is working version, so pretty sloppy). The results are (very) different for different browsers with Chrome getting all the points for speed, and Opera a good second - but that's not the question here.

In Firefox I detected a problem with clearing a div (from it's childNodes). When some 50.000 div elements are added, it takes ages to clear, using just

```
[div].innerHTML = "";
```

What is going on here? Did firefox implement some intrinsic garbage collection method for this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

While I am not sure about the innerHTML = "" you left out one possibly fast appoach using DocumentFragments for inserting into the DOM: [As John Resig shows](http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/).

As Ólafur Waage already mentioned, even though innerHTML is faster in a lot of situations since it's not part of any [W3C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Wide_Web_Consortium) standard, quirks are far more likely to be introduced then if they were. Not to say innerHTML is not a defacto standard within modern browsers.

[This blog post](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-than-innerhtml) seems to indicate that Firefox spends a lot of time cleaning up after itself when using innerHTML to remove elements.

> In some browsers (most notably, Firefox), although innerHTML is generally much faster than DOM methods, it spends a disproportionate amount of time clearing out existing elements vs. creating new ones. Knowing this, we can combine the speed of destroying elements by removing their parent using the standard DOM methods with creating new elements using innerHTML.

Comment: Yes, completely missed the DocumentFragments! Opens up new ideas, thanks. The blog link is spot on too.

Comment: Old question but I think this guy deserves credit for the earliest publishing of the combo method that I'm aware of. This may be less significant in the modern corp of JIT-equipped browsers but it still works great as far as I can tell: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/faster-than-innerhtml

Answer (score 2):

innerHTML is not a part of the W3C DOM specification.

> It should never be used to write parts of a table—W3C DOM methods should be used for that—though it can be used to write an entire table or the contents of a cell.
>
> As there is no public specification for this property, implementations differ widely. For example, when text is entered into a text input, IE will change the value attribute of the input's innerHTML property but Gecko browsers do not.
>
> For those wishing to adhere to standards, [here is one set of JavaScript functions](http://innerdom.sourceforge.net/) offering to serialize or parse XML so as to set element contents defined as string(s) via the DOM or getting element contents obtained from the DOM as a string.

[Source - Mozilla Dev](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.innerHTML)

Comment: I am not writing (part of) a table. The testpage produces 50.000 divs within a container div, using different methods. The problem with innerHTML = '' only occurs in Firefox and I'm curious as to what causes it. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: I think the quote answers your question just fine. "As there is no public specification for this property, implementations differ widely."

Comment: `innerHTML` is defined in the [DOM Parsing](http://html5.org/specs/dom-parsing.html) spec.